# C++11 default constructor behavior with class member default value

Tags: c++, c++11

This question is for C++11.

In the following struct *A*, will *x* always be 42, when the default constructor is used?

```
struct A{
  A() = default;
private:
  int x = 42;
}
```

In short, I'm wondering if the default constructor guarantees that default member values will be set.

Comment: [stroustrup answers it best](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init)

Comment: That's not a great dupe.

Comment: @SamerTufail That page doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There is a line a about `if a member is initialized by both an in-class initializer and a constructor, only the constructor's initialization is done (it "overrides" the default)`, so it does seem to suggest that by default it would set the member values if the default ctor is used.

Comment: @SamerTufail Hmm I suppose so. Not very explicit but okay :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit come on its stroustruppppp :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Unfortunately the wording below is from the standard draft as of today, but the principle is the same in C++11.

> [`[class.default.ctor]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#class.default.ctor-4) A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is *odr-used* (`[basic.def.odr]`) to create an object of its class type (`[intro.object]`), when it is needed for constant evaluation (`[expr.const]`), or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration. **The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no *ctor-initializer* (`[class.base.init]`) and an empty *compound-statement*.**
>
> [`[class.base.init]/9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#9) In a non-delegating constructor, if a given potentially constructed subobject is not designated by a *mem-initializer-id* (including **the case where there is no *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no *ctor-initializer***), then:
>
> 1. if the entity is a non-static data member that has a default member initializer (`[class.mem]`) and either
>
>    1. the constructor's class is a union (`[class.union]`), and no other variant member of that union is designated by a *mem-initializer-id* or
>    2. the constructor's class is not a union, and, if the entity is a member of an anonymous union, no other member of that union is designated by a *mem-initializer-id*, **the entity is initialized from its default member initializer as specified in `[dcl.init]`**;
>
> *[..]*

---

> In short, I'm wondering if the default constructor guarantees that default member values will be set.

[An example of exactly this](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#9.3) follows the passage latterly quoted above.

---

However, if you were to define `A::A()` and provide an initialiser for `x`, [it would take precedence over the inline initialiser](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-10).

Comment: This answer is correct but much of the text you have quoted is not in the C++11 standard unfortunately (n3337).

Comment: @P.W Ah, shame. Might revisit it with C++11 wording if I can be bothered to dig it up but for now my time allotted to this question has expired!