# Does value initialization of an aggregate use its member's default initializer?

Tags: c++

If I have an aggregate struct, with default initializers for its members. If I value initialize the aggregate, are the members initialized with the initializers, or are they value initialized?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
struct Foo{
    std::array<bool, 2> x = {true, true};
};

int main(){
    std::unordered_map<int, Foo> f;
    std::cout << f[0].x[1];
}
```

`unordered_map::operator[]` value initialize the `value_type` if the key does not exist. Does value initialization of `Foo` use my default initializer? Is the program guaranteed to output `1`?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

The map's element initialisation will be via default constructor.

And, per [my previous answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707797/560648), this honours your default initializer.

---

> `[unord.map.elem]:` `mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& k);`
>   [1/](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.map.elem#1) **Effects:** Equivalent to: `return try_­emplace(k).first->second;`

> `[unord.map]:` `template<class... Args> pair<iterator, bool> try_emplace(const key_type& k, Args&&... args);`
>   [6/](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.map#modifiers-6) **Effects:** If the map already contains an element whose key is equivalent to `k`, there is no effect. Otherwise inserts an object of type `value_­type` constructed with `piecewise_­construct, forward_­as_­tuple(k), forward_­as_­tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.

> `[pairs]:` `template<class... Args1, class... Args2> constexpr pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<Args1...> first_args, tuple<Args2...> second_args);`
>   [/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/pairs#pair-15): **Effects:** Initializes `first` with arguments of types `Args1...` obtained by forwarding the elements of `first_args` and initializes `second` with arguments of types `Args2...` obtained by forwarding the elements of `second_­args`. (Here, forwarding an element `x` of type `U` within a `tuple` object means calling `std::forward<U>(x)`.) This form of construction, whereby constructor arguments for `first` and `second` are each provided in a separate tuple object, is called *piecewise construction*.

*(recall that `Args2...` is empty here, so no constructor arguments are provided to `Foo`, but the mechanism is still that as for constructor usage)*

Comment: Thank you. If the Foo is defined as   
`struct Foo{
    std::array<bool, 2> x;
};`
Is the program guaranteed to output 0?

Comment: @Hui I don't believe so